# Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a software for a gym but I'm getting this error and I don't know why, I've trying for hours but nothing

```
  CREATE TABLE Socios (
    IdSocio INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Nombre VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Apellido VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    N_Celular VARCHAR(12),
    Correo VARCHAR(60),
    Fecha_Nacimiento DATE NOT NULL,
    Fecha_Asociacion DATE NOT NULL,
    Fecha_Modificacion DATE NOT NULL,
    Notas VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (IdSocio)
)  ENGINE=INNODB; 

CREATE TABLE tipos(
  IdTipos INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Tipo VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
  Precio DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (IdTipos)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE productos (
IdProducto INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Producto VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
Descripcion VARCHAR (100),
Costo_Individual DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,
Precio_venta DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,
Estado BOOL NOT NULL,
Cantidad_Inicial INT NOT NULL,
Cantidad_actual INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(IdProducto)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint 
I'm getting this error for this tables

```
CREATE TABLE membresia(
IdMembresia INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
Nombre VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Tipo VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Fecha_Inicio DATE NOT NULL,
Fecha_Vencimiento DATE NOT NULL, 
Inscripcion BOOL NOT NULL,
Estado_membresia VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
Fecha_modificacion DATE NOT NULL,
Total DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,
Nota VARCHAR(100), 
Fecha_Nota DATE, 
PRIMARY KEY (IdMembresia),
CONSTRAINT IdSocio FOREIGN KEY (Nombre)
      REFERENCES Socios (Nombre),
CONSTRAINT IdTipos FOREIGN KEY (Tipo,Total)
  REFERENCES tipos (Tipo,Precio)
) ENGINE = INNODB;


CREATE TABLE ventas (
IdVenta INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Producto VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
Fecha_venta DATE NOT NULL,
cantidad INT NOT NULL,
Total DECIMAL(8,2),
Fecha_Modificacion DATE NOT NULL,
Nota VARCHAR (100),
PRIMARY KEY (IdVenta),
CONSTRAINT IdProducto FOREIGN KEY (Producto) 
    REFERENCES productos(Producto)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Comment: FOREIGN KEY has been primary key of table. In your code column does not have primary key..

Comment: In what column? all of them have primary keys @MukeshKalgude

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server here? Don't tag products not involved...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you over an initial hurdle. Though I doubt you really want an FK on a price but I don't know the translation into your mother tongue.

You need indexes on the *referenced* tables for the columns looked up in FK's.

```
create schema dbtest_xyz;
use dbtest_xyz;

 -- drop table Socios;
  CREATE TABLE Socios (
    IdSocio INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Nombre VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Apellido VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    N_Celular VARCHAR(12),
    Correo VARCHAR(60),
    Fecha_Nacimiento DATE NOT NULL,
    Fecha_Asociacion DATE NOT NULL,
    Fecha_Modificacion DATE NOT NULL,
    Notas VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (IdSocio),
    key(Nombre) -- ADDED *******************************
)  ENGINE=INNODB; 

-- drop table tipos;
CREATE TABLE tipos(
  IdTipos INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Tipo VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
  Precio DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (IdTipos),
  key(Tipo),    -- ADDED *******************************
  key(Precio)   -- ADDED *******************************
) ENGINE = INNODB;

-- drop table productos;
CREATE TABLE productos (
IdProducto INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Producto VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
Descripcion VARCHAR (100),
Costo_Individual DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,
Precio_venta DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,
Estado BOOL NOT NULL,
Cantidad_Inicial INT NOT NULL,
Cantidad_actual INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(IdProducto),
key(Producto) -- ADDED *******************************
) ENGINE = INNODB;


CREATE TABLE membresia(
IdMembresia INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
Nombre VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Tipo VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Fecha_Inicio DATE NOT NULL,
Fecha_Vencimiento DATE NOT NULL, 
Inscripcion BOOL NOT NULL,
Estado_membresia VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
Fecha_modificacion DATE NOT NULL,
Total DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,
Nota VARCHAR(100), 
Fecha_Nota DATE, 
PRIMARY KEY (IdMembresia),
CONSTRAINT IdSocio FOREIGN KEY (Nombre)
      REFERENCES Socios (Nombre),
CONSTRAINT IdTipos FOREIGN KEY (Tipo)
      REFERENCES tipos (Tipo),
CONSTRAINT IdMembresia FOREIGN KEY (Total)
      REFERENCES tipos (Precio)
) ENGINE = INNODB;


CREATE TABLE ventas (
IdVenta INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Producto VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
Fecha_venta DATE NOT NULL,
cantidad INT NOT NULL,
Total DECIMAL(8,2),
Fecha_Modificacion DATE NOT NULL,
Nota VARCHAR (100),
PRIMARY KEY (IdVenta),
CONSTRAINT IdProducto FOREIGN KEY (Producto) 
    REFERENCES productos(Producto)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

-- Cleanup:
drop schema dbtest_xyz;
```

Mysql Manual Page on [Foreign Keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
>   referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an
>   index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
>   exist. This index might be silently dropped later, if you create
>   another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint.
>   index_name, if given, is used as described previously.

Note, the reason I have the `drop tables` above some tables is that it is wise to have them in place while one iteratively attempts the creations. When the FK creations fail, one often (almost always) has to re-jigger the *referenced* and *referencing* tables.

Comment: Thanks so much, It's my first day with MySQL and this help me so much, I didn't knew all those things.

Comment: Sorry, I still have the error in the membresia table :/

Comment: Right, because your old tables were in some funky state. The details and what is in place and the sequence ... matters.

Answer (score 1):

Your first 2 tables should be as per below, means referenced fields should be indexed.

```
CREATE TABLE Socios (
    IdSocio INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Nombre VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Apellido VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    N_Celular VARCHAR(12),
    Correo VARCHAR(60),
    Fecha_Nacimiento DATE NOT NULL,
    Fecha_Asociacion DATE NOT NULL,
    Fecha_Modificacion DATE NOT NULL,
    Notas VARCHAR(100),
    KEY idx_Nombre(Nombre),
    PRIMARY KEY (IdSocio)
)  ENGINE=INNODB; 

CREATE TABLE tipos(
  IdTipos INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Tipo VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
  Precio DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,
  KEY idx_tipo_precio(Tipo,Precio),
  PRIMARY KEY (IdTipos)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Comment: Precio won't work in the composite because it is not left-most. The manual page specifies that, plus it won't work if you test it.

Comment: @Drew: I checked and it is working fine. Please elaborate if you are getting any issue or it will be helpful if you can provide any link related with it.

Comment: `KEY idx_tipo_precio(Tipo,Precio)` makes a composite key with Precio non left-most

Comment: so when CREATE TABLE membresia( .... comes along, it fails because only 2 out of 3 of its FK's have left-most indexes available in the referenced table(s)

Comment: plz check sql fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d66b9 if you execute following statement "INSERT INTO membresia VALUES(1,'abc',10.00,CURDATE());" then fine but if you insert any row which break foreign key rule then will not allow to insert. It means it is working fine...Further it is not an argue but I want to test it and need your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

In case this may help someone else one day, I had this issue yet none of the existing solutions helped - columns were same type, same collation, etc.

However, I had a stored generated column in the table containing the foreign key that referenced that key column, and for some reason this broke the foreign key generation. Removing the generated column and using a trigger instead fixed it.